# Repetition of elements in a group, where am I wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am employing a particular method by which I am getting absurd results. I can not figure out where I am mistaking.

Say $G$ is an abelian group of order 9. Let $a \in G$, so I am representing the elements of group as $a, a^{2}, a^{3},...,a^{9}$. By cauchy's theorem, $a^{3}=e$ and therefore $a^{6}=e$. So I have 3 elements of a group which are equal to $e$, but the order of the group is 9 and all the elements of a group are supposed to be distinct.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem **does not** assert $a^3=e$. Even if $a^3=e$ is true in $G$, then there still isn't a problem. In that case, the fact that $a,a^2,\cdots,a^9$ is really only three elements doesn't contradict the fact that $G$ has order $9$, it just means you haven't listed all of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy's theorem states that there *exists* an element of order $3$, not that every element has order $3$. (You might be confusing this with Lagrange's theorem, which says that every element has order (dividing) $|G|$ for $G$ finite.) It also looks like you're assuming $G$ is cyclic. It's just abelian; you could have, for example, $G = \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: I could be wrong but, since $G$ is closed and as $a \in G$, so wouldn't $a^{2}, a^{3},...,a^{9} \in G$?

Comment: @Mad yes, what's your point?

Comment: @blue so I am not taking it as cyclic.

Comment: @Mad "taking it"?

Comment: @blue I am not assuming the group to be cyclic. Is this alright? BTW your other comment was helpful and now I have understood.

Comment: @MadRumours: You **have** assumed that your group is cyclic, when you wrote "I am representing the elements of group as $a,a^2,a^3,…,a^9$": an order 9 abelian group can be represented in that fashion if and only if it is cyclic. Noncyclic order 9 abelian groups, such as $\mathbb{Z}/3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3$, cannot be represented in that fashion.